# Data changes on console / dashboard not reflected in app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app currently observes changes on .value, like so:

```
ref.child("user/tasks").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
})
```

When changes to data are made via the iOS app, there are no problems and it is updated in real-time.

However, when I clear data from the dashboard at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/... the app does not sync with that updated data. In fact, I have to delete and re-install the app for it to recognize that I deleted data from the dashboard.

Is there a certain query that I should be using to recognize these changes, as well?

Comment: Are you saying that you app does get the initial tasks, but does not receive updates? That would be quite unusual.

Comment: Are there *any* calls in your app to removeAllObservers or removeObserverWithHandle? Do you call onDisconnect anywhere?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When data is removed from the database, I have to uninstall the app from the iPhone or simulator for the app to recognize that data has been removed, which makes me think something is going on with persistence?

Comment: That indeed sounds like disk persistence. But it's impossible to say anything conclusive with just the code you shared.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I retrieve my data with the method call in my original post (observing .value) - is there anything specific I can share that can help further? Thank you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is indeed related to persistence; when I set         FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = false, my app does not continue to recognize data that was previously removed from the server. So now I'm just wondering if there is a way to have persistenceEnabled set to true, but while also having it be able to recognize when data on the server has been removed

Comment: If you add a listener for the data that has been removed from the server, it will initially fire with the local state and then once more with the state from the server. So if you show the data in a UI, you will briefly see the old value before it is removed.